# Hollow Object BoolTool Union Issue

Tags: scripting, modifiers, add-on

I have objects A and B. Both of them are part of a large 3D rectangular object. As they were extracted from the original object, they have some open portion as shown in the image

[image]

When I try to use BoolTool to union the A and B, it does not perform well and often just keep A or B without merging with the other one. For example -

```
BoolTool Union of A and B = just A or just B
```

If I manually filled the open sides of both objects, the BoolTool performs exactly is supposed to be.

```
BoolTool Union of A and B = Union of A and B
```

Is there any way for BoolTool to work on the objects with open sides? I have thousands of objects and filling the sides one by one is not a viable option.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid not, the boolean works best with closed meshes, for open meshes, you can get lucky, but usually it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any way of closing all the opening with python scripts?

Comment: You'd have to search for a script. If the objects and their openings are really similar, you might be able to write it yourself. Not much hope for that, though.